# Doing a file upload with python-oauth2

Tags: python, file-upload, oauth

A Get request is pretty easy:

```
def build_request(url, method='GET'):
    params = {                                            
        'oauth_version': "1.0",
        'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time())
    }
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key='****',secret='******')
    params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

    req = oauth2.Request(method=method, url=url, parameters=params)
    signature_method = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, None)
    return req
```

But now, we want to make a POST with a file. (We're using the library python-oauth2). Suggestions?

Comment: I made example here, with API v2 https://gist.github.com/1242662
Thanks for @jterrace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that oauth is not supposed to sign multipart/post data, but it still needs to sign the other parameters. The way I got around it was to use python-oauth2 to sign the non-file parameters and then send the request manually with urllib2.

Here's an [example script](https://github.com/ourbricks/ourbricks-api-examples/blob/master/python/upload2ourbricks.py#L126-173). See lines 126 - 173.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the source it appears that Request takes a method to state with HTTP request to use.

Simply change your req to

```
req = oauth2.Request(method='POST', url=url, parameters=params)
```

[https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/**init**.py#L342](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py#L342) for more info

That might go part way to solving your issue, as for the file upload you might be aable to work with supplying headers with the content see:

[https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/**init**.py#L646](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py#L646)

Apologies I have not had chance to test this yet.